# UNICODE version supported by SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2016

What is the Unicode standard version supported by SQL Server 2016? *(I'm specifically interested in this version. However, information for 2014 or 2017 is welcome as well.)*

I can't find this information in Technet / MSDN. The only information I was able to find, is [this blog post](https://devio.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/unicode-versions-supported-in-sql-server-2000-2012/) that states Unicode versions up until SQL Server 2012.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/frequently-asked-questions-faq-for-odbc-linux say: `UTF-8 for SQL_CHAR data and UTF-16 for SQL_WCHAR data.` but not specific Unicode version

Comment: @Nolwennig Yes, I was able to find that. However UTF-8/16 is such the encoding, and provides no information regarding the actual Unicode Standard version supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was looking at this myself today. Turns out I can do Unicode 9 on SQL 2016 without issues.

```
CREATE TABLE [Test].[dbo].[](
    [] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Works perfectly. So I even can do this:

```
SELECT  FROM dbo. WHERE  =
```

I wasn't able to test Unicode 10 since my OS (2012 R2 for my test server doesn't support it). SQL Server never struggled, doing it with SSMS was trickier, so I did it via Powershell.

Comment: Great and funny answer! :D In fact the select statement closely represents my current health condition.